# Controlar versão do módulo com Maven

Tags: java, maven

Tenho um projeto Java multi-módulo com Maven.

Atualmente, controlo a versão de cada módulo manualmente, editando o elemento `<version>` do pom.xml de cada módulo que sofre atualizações.

Acredito que este não seja o método correto/indicado. Existe algo automatizado para isto?

Comment: Você usa versões `-SNAPSHOT`s? Ou o seu problema é quando fecha a versão (_release_)?

Comment: Não uso -SNAPSHOT, a dúvida é só para quando fecha mesmo.

Answer (score 6):

Caso todos seus projetos estejam controlados no mesmo pom crie uma propriedade:

```xml
<project ...>
    <properties>
        <my.project.version>1.0</my.project.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

E depois utilize onde você quiser como:

```java
<version>${my.project.version}</version>
```

---

Um outro modo de fazer esse fechamento de versão automatizado é utilizando o plugin release do maven (http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/).

Nesse caso ao disparar `mvn release:prepare` o maven simulará um fechamento de versão para você. Com isso ele altera a versão dos artefatos  (todos que estiverem com SNAPSHOT, ele perguntará se você quer fazer a tag) e faz commit no SVN.

Após o `prepare` ser finalizado com sucesso você realiza o comando `mvn release:perform` que faz o 'commit' das alterações.

Esse plugin ele pode integrar com o SVN e também com o JIRA.

Caso algum erro tenha acontecido é possível utilizar `mvn:rollback` para desfazer as alterações.

Mais detalhes olhe os links abaixos:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_deployment_automation.htm
https://weblogs.java.net/blog/johnsmart/archive/2008/08/using_the_maven.html

Comment: Se eu herdar a versão eu terei uma nova versão de cada módulo em toda e qualquer alteração. Não me parece muito bom fazer isso. Pensei que houvesse uma forma de automatizar o versionamento do módulo.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta para incluir a automatização. [=

Comment: Valeu @uaiHebert. Vou estudar este plugin... Entretanto, tenho aqui o Jenkins (instalei a tempos para testes) e estive pensando... Não seria mais lógico o Jenkins ser o responsável por realizar o processo de versionamento e preparar os arquivos para o deploy (.war)?

Comment: Não vejo muita lógica no Jenkins fazer isso, afinal olha como ele se define:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Meet+Jenkins

Building/testing software projects continuously + 
Monitoring executions of externally-run jobs

Pode até ter como integrá-lo ao plugin do maven, mas no momento não sei como seria feito isso. [=

Comment: É, acho que foi meio viagem minha mesmo... eu pensei no Jenkins fazendo os testes e gerando um novo build com a versão incrementada...